# Laplace equation in a rectangle, Dirichlet to Neumann map

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem

$$\Delta u = 0,(x,y) \in \Omega=(0,1)^2 \\
u(0,y)=u(1,y)=1 \\
u(x,0)=u(x,1)=0.$$

This problem can be solved exactly. The solution is

$$u(x,y)=4\sum_{\text{odd } n} \frac{1}{n\pi} \sin(n\pi x) \left ( 1 - \frac{\sinh(n\pi y)+\sinh(n\pi(1-y))}{\sinh(n\pi)} \right ).$$

Note that the boundary conditions on the left and right edges are not strictly speaking satisfied; these are only satisfied in a weak sense. Essentially the right way to think about this is to round the corners out into quarter-circles of a small radius $r$, make the boundary value go smoothly (but rapidly) from $0$ to $1$ around each corner, and then take the limit $r \to 0$. In the limit $r \to 0$ there is a Gibbs phenomenon appearing which spoils the boundary conditions.

I am trying to analytically compute or approximate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1)$. Unfortunately, it appears that the convergence properties of this sum are too bad to allow term-by-term differentiation with respect to $y$ (which is not a huge surprise, because the boundary conditions are singular at the corners). How can this be circumvented to extract the boundary derivative data?

Comment: I think you might have $x$ and $y$ the wrong way round, either in the BCs or in the expression for $u$.

Comment: @Chappers I think it is correct, try plotting a truncation of $\sum_{\text{odd } n} \frac{\sin(n \pi x)}{n\pi}$ to see what's happening. It's not formally correct, but it cannot be, due to the corner singularities.

Comment: @Winther The target is really an analytical approximation, because the primary interest is a problem with a few different parameters that I have set equal to $1$ for purposes of the question.

Comment: @Winther I'm not seeing where the $\tanh$ comes in (it seems like if anything there would be a $\coth$), can you explain that? Good idea in general though.

Comment: @Dylan No, that's not right. The solution is *defined* to be zero on the top and bottom edges. The solution I wrote is also, strictly speaking, zero on the left and right edges, but this is a Gibbs phenomenon effect resulting from the corner singularities. Something like this is necessarily going to happen, because the problem is singular.

Comment: The main problem I have with this solution is it doesn't satisfy the Laplace equation. Particularly, the terms that are constant in $y$. Can you elaborate further on why it should satisfy the boundary, in a weak sense? Your comments on the limits $r \to 0$ is not very clear to me. 

The right solution, to me, should be
$$ u(x,y) = \sum_{n=2k+1} \frac{4}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi y) \frac{\sinh(n\pi x) + \sinh(n\pi(1-x))}{\sinh(n\pi)} $$

Do you think the above is *not* the correct solution, or do you think it's *equivalent* to your solution?

Comment: @Dylan It is not a sum of terms each of which satisfy the Laplace equation. The full infinite sum $\sum_{n=2k+1} \frac{4}{n\pi} \sin(n\pi x)$ satisfies the Laplace equation because it is actually just $1$ away from the boundary (thus I suppose you can consign all the bad behavior to the corners instead of the edges by writing this term as $1$).

Comment: @Dylan (Cont.) I constructed this by using the Green's function, choosing to do so by putting the $\sin$'s on $x$ and the $\sinh$'s on $y$. One can also put the $\sin$'s on $y$ and the $\sinh$'s on $x$ in the way you wrote; I haven't worked it out myself but presumably it would result in something like your solution. I wanted to use this form of the Green's function because my real problem is on $(0,a) \times (0,b)$ with $a \ll b$, so I presumed this form of the Green's function would converge faster.

Comment: @Dylan Indeed once you make the identification $\sum_{n=2k+1} \frac{4}{n\pi} \sin(n\pi x)=1$, our solutions coincide.

Comment: You're right. I see it now. Swapping $x$ and $y$ from my series (which I found using separation of variables), and subtracting it from $1$ becomes your series. So they are the same after all.

Comment: If we use my version of the solution, then differentiating term-by-term gives

$$ u_y(x,1) = -4\sum_{n=2k+1}\frac{\sinh(n\pi x) + \sinh(n\pi(1-x))}{\sinh(n\pi)} $$

Do you think this converges?

Comment: @Dylan Away from the left and right edges (where singularity is inevitable) it does indeed converge, so this is a considerable improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we naively compute the derivative term by term we end up with a divergent series. However the partial sums of this series will oscillate about the true solution. We can obtain an approximation by adding an exponential regulator which leads to the following approximation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1) \approx -4\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\sin(n\pi x) \tanh(\pi n/ 2)e^{-\epsilon n}$$

To check how good this approximation is we need the numerical solution. Luckily this is very easy to obtain in Mathematica:

```
(* Solve the PDE numerically *)
equation = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
dirichletconditons = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 1],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 0], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 1]};
domain = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
method = {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}
f = NDSolveValue[{equation, dirichletconditons}, u, {x, y} \[Element] domain, Method -> method];
dfdy = Derivative[0, 1][f];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

For the approximation we fix $\epsilon$ and sum up to high enough $n_{\rm max}$ such that higher order terms are negligible

```
(* Compare numerical solution to analytical approximation *)
\[Epsilon] = 0.01;
nmax = Floor[5.0/\[Epsilon]];
dfdyapprox[x_] := Sum[-4 Sin[\[Pi] n x] Tanh[\[Pi] n/2] Exp[-\[Epsilon] n], {k, 1, nmax, 2}];
Plot[{dfdy[x, 1], dfdyapprox[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

which gives an almost perfect match (the two curves lie on top of each other here)

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Now if we make the approximation $\tanh(x)\approx 1$ in the sum above we can evaluate the sum and take $\epsilon \to 0$ to get
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1) \approx \frac{4 \sin (\pi  x)}{\cos (2 \pi  x)-1}$$
which turns out to be a quite good approximation

[image]

and this can be improved even further by adding $-4\sum_{n=1,3,5,(2N+1)}\sin(n\pi x)[\tanh(n\pi/2)-1]$ for some small $N$. Turns out adding just one term gives a result that accurate to $0.1\%$ for most $[0,1]$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,1) \approx 4 \sin (\pi  x) \left(\frac{1}{\cos (2 \pi  x)-1}+1-\tanh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Not a correction, just an interesting comment. If you consider doing the same calculation on a general rectangular domain, this $\tanh$ approximation is more and more accurate as the domain becomes more and more narrow, i.e. if the domain is $[0,a] \times [0,b]$ then it becomes a better estimate as $a/b \to 0$. Thankfully, this is exactly the extreme limit I wanted to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative series is just fine for $0 < y < 1$:
$$
    u_{y}(x,y) = 4\sum_{\mbox{odd $n$}}\sin(n\pi x)\frac{\cosh(n\pi(1-y))-\cosh(n\pi y)}{\sinh(n\pi)}
$$
For $\delta < y < 1-\delta$ the fraction in the sum is bounded by $C e^{-n\pi\delta}$.

Comment: Sure, but you can't send $y \to 1^-$ without fully evaluating the sum, since the sum with $y$ set equal to $1$ is divergent. But maybe you *can* fully evaluate the sum...